# Interactive rebase changes order without being prompted

Tags: git, rebase

I observed an unexpected behavior in an interactive rebase today.
It was always my understanding that if I run an interactive rebase and don't change *anything* in the editor, it should not have any effect, but apparently that's not so (at least on a specific repo im working with which sadly I cannot share).

Lets say we have

`A -> B -> C -> D <--HEAD`

and I run `git rebase -i A` I expect to see

```
pick B
pick C
pick D
```

but in the repo I'm working on I got

```
pick C
pick B
pick D
```

instead.
If I close the editor and git does its thing, the result is:

`A -> C' -> B' -> D' <--HEAD`

Does anybody know what circumstances might lead to a behavior like that?

Comment: They should indeed be in topo order. To make sure you're seeing topo order, use `git log --graph` or `git log --topo-order`. If they're not properly sorted, that's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you inspected your history by running `git log`.

When your intention is to view the history of your repo (with your own human eyes, as opposed to using `git log` to extract data for a script), I strongly suggest to add the `--graph` option, otherwise you are "history blind" and do not see how commits are related to one another :

```
# a very handy command to view your repo's history:
git log --oneline --graph

# Someone once said he aliased this to 'git lol' and I stuck with it:
git config --global alias.lol "log --oneline --graph"

git lol
git lol master origin/master
git lol --all
...
```

---

You describe something you can see if your history contains a merge commit of some sort :

```
* D
* merged
|\
| * C
* | B
|/
* A
```

Comment: Ah that was it. Obvious in hindsight, came in with the wrong assumptions of what had previously happened on the branch. Thanks for the info!